# Conversión fallida en sentencia SQL en C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Tengo un problema al querer ejecutar una sentencia SQL, me explico quiero mostrar información dependiendo de un numero que mando por parámetro, pero al momento de ejecutar mi consulta me arroja la siguiente excepción
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi sentencia que hago es la siguiente y en donde me arroja la excepcion

```html
public List<cDireccionEmbarque> obtenerDireccion(string customer_id)
        {
            DataFramework.Query q = new DataFramework.Query()
                .SelAs("CUSTOMER_ID", "ca.CUSTOMER_ID")
                .SelAs("SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO", "ca.ADDR_NO")
                .SelAs("NAME", "ca.NAME")
                .FromAs("ca", "CUST_ADDRESS")
                .Where("CUSTOMER_ID", customer_id)
                .OrderBy("ca.NAME");
            return Tools.Connection.Fima.ExecList<cDireccionEmbarque>(q);
        }
```

en este metodo declaro una variable string para recibir el valor del siguiente codigo

```html
opedidoMigradoLinea.listaEmbarque = obtenerDireccion(opedidoMigradoLinea.CUSTOMER_ID);
```

en esa linea de codigo el .CUSTOMER_ID me devuelve un numero, ya debuggeando mi codigo en este caso me devuelve un 5, y ese CUSTOMER_ID lo obtengo de mi clase y lo tengo de la siguiente manera

```html
public string CUSTOMER_ID { get; set; }
```

y al momento de ejecutar mi sentencia en sql server me arroja el mismo error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al momento de poner comillas simples a mi valor devuelto (5) si me arroja la información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero saber es como poder solventar ese problema en mi método donde hago esa sentencia 
si requieren mas explicación estaré al pendiente

Comment: El error parece referirse a otro contexto en el cual un valor `249-1` intenta ser convertido a fecha. En el código que muestras no veo ninguna columna del tipo `DATETIME`. ¿Qué hay en la línea 140?

Comment: El tipo de dato nvarchar es texto estas intentado igualar dos tipos de datos distintos debido a que el tipo de la base de datos es nvarchar tu tipo de dato a igualar en tu codigo c# o la consulta sql debiera ser un string también. Saludos

Comment: @MaximilianoFlores si de hecho el tipo de dato que quiero es string lo tengo declarado como string, seguiré buscando si por el código tengo un int que me causa el conflicto, gracias

Comment: Por tu query tienes un CUSTOMER_ID con un - por eso sale el error, puedes probar where isnumeric(Customer_ID) = 1 and customer_id = 5

Answer (score 1):

El error de conversión es porque CUSTOMER-ID como ya te han indicado tiene un "-", si quieres obtener donde, tienes carácteres no numéricos, puedes encontrarlos:

```
Select * from Cust_address
where try_Cast(id as int) is null
```

otra opción

```
Select * from Cust_address
Where isNumeric(id) =0
```